# Group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$ with special property on $G$

Tags: group-theory, modules, group-rings

‎Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$‎. ‎Then a  homomorphism $r:G\to H$ is said to be a *retraction* if the inclusion  homomorphism $i:H\hookrightarrow G$ is a right inverse of $r$‎, ‎i.e‎. ‎$r(x)=x$ for all elements $x\in H$‎. ‎Then $H$ is called  a *retract* of $G$‎ and denoted by $H<_r G$ (we can define retracts of $R$-modules similarly, which I call $R$-retracts).

A group $G$ is said to satisfy the descending chain conditions on retracts  if for every chain of $G_1 >_r G_2 >_r \cdots$ of retracts of $G$ there is an integer $n$ such that $G_i = G_n$ for all $i\geq n$.

**My question** : Assume that $G$ satisfies the descending chain conditions on retracts and $M$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}G$-module. Does $M$ satisfy the descending chain conditions on $\mathbb{Z}G$-retracts?

Comment: I don't suppose that I can answer this question, but could you say what you mean by a ${\mathbb Z}G$-retract?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks fot the comment. I mean a $\mathbb{Z}G$-module of $M$ which is also a retact.

Comment: In the definition of retraction, you probably meant to write $r$, not $f$.

Comment: @jjagmath You are right. I've just edited it.

Comment: @AnneBauval Not necessarily.

Comment: @AnneBauval As I mentioned in the question, $G$ satisfies the descending chain conditions on retracts. So $G_i$ are ,in fact, retracts of $G$. So if $G_{i+1}$ is a subgroup of $G_i$, it is a retract of $G_i$ automatically.

Comment: I see. Then what you "mentionned in the question" will be clearer if you edit your post to replace " $G_1 >_r G_2 >_r \cdots$ of retracts $G$ " with " $G_1 >G_2 >\cdots$ of retracts of $G$", or at least insert "of" before "$G$" (thereby allowing the redundancy you kindly explained), or (as first suggested) simply replace "$G_1 >_r G_2 >_r \cdots$ of retracts $G$" with "$G=G_1 >_r G_2 >_r \cdots$".

Comment: @AnneBauval You are right. I got it. I'll edit it. Thank you very much for the comment.